# How do I skip a line COBOL?

Tags: cobol

I have a cobol project and everything works and prints fine except I can't figure out how to skip a line between address.

Action code:

```
200-PROCESS-ONE-RECORD.
   MOVE NAME-IN TO LEFT-LABEL-OUT
   MOVE SPACES TO BLANK-OUT
   MOVE NAME-IN TO RIGHT-LABEL-OUT
   MOVE SPACES TO BLANK-A-OUT
   WRITE LABEL-RECORD-OUT
   
   MOVE ADDRESS-IN TO LEFT-LABEL-OUT
   MOVE SPACES TO BLANK-OUT
   MOVE ADDRESS-IN TO RIGHT-LABEL-OUT
   MOVE SPACES TO BLANK-A-OUT
   WRITE LABEL-RECORD-OUT
   
   MOVE CITY-STATE-ZIP-IN TO LEFT-LABEL-OUT
   MOVE SPACES TO BLANK-OUT
   MOVE CITY-STATE-ZIP-IN TO RIGHT-LABEL-OUT
   MOVE SPACES TO BLANK-A-OUT
   WRITE LABEL-RECORD-OUT
```

It currently print like this:

```
IAN HENDERSON                      IAN HENDERSON
1309 SPRINGBANK ST.                1309 SPRINGBANK ST.
DETROIT     MI 48024               DETROIT     MI 48024
JANET LEASA                        JANET LEASA
12700 GRATIOT ST.                  12700 GRATIOT ST.
WARREN      MI 48077               WARREN      MI 48077
```

I need a space/empty line between lines 3 and 4. In this case an empty line between DETROIT and Janet.

Comment: Use `BEFORE/AFTER ADVANCING ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either

```
MOVE SPACE TO LABEL-RECORD-OUT
WRITE LABEL-RECORD-OUT
```

Or

```
WRITE LABEL-RECORD-OUT FROM SPACE
```

Wherever a blank line is needed. This fits the pattern from the code you have shown.

One would need to see the record description entry for `LABEL-RECORD-OUT` to make it more clear that the above would answer the question.